# Anonymizing part of a Git repository's history

Tags: git

I'm trying to anonymize Git commits that happened within a specific time frame, such as between 2018-01-01 and 2019-04-31. I found out about the `git filter-branch` command, but by default it appears to affect the entire history. I then learned that you're supposedly able to filter the affected commits with `<rev-list options>`, but when I try to pass a time option to it, I get an error.

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter '
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="anonymous"
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="anonymous"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="anonymous"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="anonymous"
' -- --after=2020-01-01
fatal: options not supported in --stdin mode
Could not get the commits
```

Calling `git ref-list` with the same parameters returns a list of the commits I'd like to modify, which I believe means that part is correct. Unfortunately I found little to no help about this error on the web.

Does anyone know what the problem could be? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Just so you know, those are not valid email addresses and even if Git lets you use that as an email address, `git fsck` will likely fail.  The address you provide really needs to meet the RFC production for an email address.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just copied that command from somewhere for testing, but I'll make sure to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use filter-branch recently and filter-branch gave me a warning that it is not considered reliable, and suggesting that I get git-filter-repo.

I was able to use git-filter-repo to accomplish the task I needed done.

https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo
https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo  (man page)